# I dont know why my code is keep on getting an error

Tags: python

```
def square(10):
    """returns the square of a number"""
    squared = 10**2
    print "%d squared is %d." % (10, squared)
    return squared
```

It keeps on saying

```
  File "python", line 1
    def square(10):
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to do some more learning before attempting this again.  You don't pass parameters in a method declaration, you pass them when you call the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the literal `10` where you should have used a parameter name. See:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm

What you really want is basically:

```
def square(x):
    """returns the square of a number"""
    squared = x**2
    print "%d squared is %d." % (10, squared)
    return squared

square(10)
```

Comment: Add the call to the function to your answer, as an example.

Comment: Good idea, I guess that makes the whole "what is a function" thing clearer